# Previously functional Bock Erupter Cubes suddenly throwing errors and will not mine

Tags: mining-hardware

For the past two months I have been mining, without incident, using the stratrum proxie on my block cubes. I run the proxie, alternating, from two different systems so I don't believe anything has changed on the PC side, or I would expect one of them to still work. The only thing that I have done, that is different, is try to change pools to a PPC pool to diversify my earning. Since I attempted to change pools I am no longer able to mine on any pool (including BTCGuild, which I have never had a problem with before. I am receiving error messages, that I cannot decipher and I'm not sure what to do about this. Has anyone else dealt with this problem before, and if so did you find a solution.

[image: here is an image of the errors I am receiving]

[image: and one more]

If anyone has any suggestion, I will be forever in your debt. I am at a complete loss, as to how to solve this problem. Thank you for taking the time to look.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance the IP address of the proxy changed? Added an Android WiFi device?

You might also post to "Dogie's Comprehensive ASICMiner Cube Setup" on [bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=352658.1320), that is ASICMiner Block Erupter Cube specific with over 1300 posts.